# JavaScript: split() but keep comma, dot, other delimiter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to parse a String which is a quote. So basically it looks like that:

```
quote.split(/[\s.,]+/)
```

That works perfectly and returns an Array as expected. But since this is a quote I don't want to loose the "," but have them as a separate element in the Array. How do I do this?

Cheers and have a nice Sunday!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put parantheses around your match group to keep your delimiter as separate elements:

```
"one,two.three four".split(/([,.\s])/);
```

will return

```
["one", ",", "two", ".", "three", " ", "four"]
```