# Split a string but keep the Comma

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

I need to split a sentence string that keeps the non-whitespace such as `.` or `,`. I need them to be included within the array string being split. Not in their own seperate array index.

```
const regex = /\W(?:\s)/g

function splitString (string) {
  return string.split(regex)
}

console.log(splitString("string one, string two, thing three, string four."))

// Output ["string one", "string two", "thing three", "string four."]
// Desired ["string one,", "string two,", "string three,", "string four."]
```

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: - ["String one,", "string two," "final string."]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: split() but keep comma, dot or whatever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801324/javascript-split-but-keep-comma-dot-or-whatever)

Comment: That splits the delimiter, I want to keep it with the previous word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps using a match approach instead of a split approach:

```
"string one, string two, thing three, four four.".match(/\w+(?:\s\w+)*\W?/g);
// [ 'string one,', 'string two,', 'thing three,', 'four four.' ]
```

or something more specific *(this way you can easily choose one or several delimiter characters)*:

```
"string one, string two, thing three, four four.".match(/\S.*?(?![^,]),?/g);
```

Comment: If anyone wants descriptions of the regex - https://regex101.com/r/1mn4J9/1